# Find and replace word with gap/wildcard in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, find-replace

Is there any way to find a specific code with one or more gaps? For example, I want to replace

```
.setImageResource(R.drawable.*)
```

with

```
.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.*))
```

Here `*` means the name will remain as was before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. You will see something like this:

[image]

Select `Regex` and then in first field paste:

```
.setImageResource\(R.drawable.(.*)\)
```

and in the second:

```
.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.$1))
```

This replacement based on Regex. In the first statement, You set the group after `R.drawable` in the `()` brackets. This group can be used in the second statement by using `$1`. `1` is the number of the group. `0` is the full regex and the next groups start integrating from `1`.

Result:

```java
.setImageResource(R.drawable.something1)
.setImageResource(R.drawable.something2)
```

was changed to

```java
.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.something1))
.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.something2))
```

---

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html) You can read more about `Find and replace with Regex` in IntelliJ IDEA